# Cannot display list from MySQL according to category in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MySQL, `categories` and `subcategories` and I'm using them to populate a dropdown list.

The arrangement that I want is like this; where when a specific category is selected the dropdown-item should be according to the main category

Problem: When a category is selected the dropdown-item is the same 
like this to all parent categories

This is the method I used to get the categories from the database

```
public function get_categories($category_table)
{
    // PURPOSE: get categories from the database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $category_table";
    $conn = $this->mysql_conn;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // var_dump($row['category_name']);
        $html = '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle list-group-item" data-toggle="dropdown">' . $row["category_name"] . '<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">'; 

        //PURPOSE: get subcategories from database and pass it to the get_categories method
        $subsql = "SELECT subcategory_name FROM subcategories WHERE category_id={$row['id']}";
        $conn = $this->mysql_conn;
        $subresult = $conn->query($subsql);

        while ($subrow = $subresult->fetch_assoc()) {
            // extract($subresult);
            // echo $subrow['subcategory_name'] . "<br>";
            $subcat_name = array();
            $subcat_name = $subrow['subcategory_name'];
            // var_dump($subrow);
         $html .= '<li><a href="#">' . $subcat_name . '</a></li>';
        }
         $html .= '</ul>';
        echo $html;
    }
}
```

THis is the html where I insert this method

```
<div class="dropdown list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Latest Products</a>
        <?php $store->get_categories('categories'); ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: Where do you try to change the drop down list?  What isn't working as expected?

Comment: You should have some ajax that calls your PHP on change of the main category.

Comment: What's the point of `$subcat_name = array();`? You immediately overwrite it with a string.

Comment: The problem is probably in the client-side Javascript or CSS that's supposed to hide and show the submenus.

Comment: @Barmar the `$subcat_name = array();` is commented its not supposed to be there..  @PatrickQ I have no background with AJAX. but the dropdown works when it was HTML and CSS only. Applying PHP by changing the variables not it does no dropdown.. I'm using bootstrap by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a list to behave like a dropdown. This will require some fancy javascript and CSS. Which library (if any) are you using to automate that.

I use bootstrap
[Bootstrap dropdown documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/)

Comment: It works with HTML and CSS only but when I applied the PHP code I'm having a hard time with the dropdown